# Creating YOLO Weights file for custom dataset

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, yolo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szDHl.jpg)I have used tiny YOLO to create a custom model. 4 files were generated in the ckpt folder corresponding to my final checkpoint. The object detection is working correctly when i give the .cfg file and load number.

I have to use cv2.dnn.readnet() to load the model and cfg file to use in raspberrypi, but the readnet fuction takes only 2 arguments, the .weights file and the .cfg file. So how do i convert my model to a single weights file?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK1Y3.jpg)

I am using python 3.7 and opencv 4.

Comment: there should be only 1 weights file for the model, why do you have 2?

Comment: @Micka There is only one weights file, the pretrained model (2nd Image).  I want to create a .weights file for my custom images instead of the 4 files created (1st Image). So that i can pass it to cv2.dnn.readnet().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an exact answer, but the repository you are using looks old. If you have the data you can retrain your custom model in `yolo v3`. This repository has all necessary information to train custom model including yolo v3 tiny,
https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet.

This will generate a `.weights` every 1000 iterations in backup folder and last weights for resuming training. You can use these weights after sufficient iterations along with the `.cfg` file in cv2.dnn.readnet().